# Dealing with access token that expires

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

What is the best way to handle an access token given by a 3rd party api that expires every hour?

Basically Im making my own stand alone api that will serve as a gateway for our other apps which in turn will be accessing the 3rd party api. Best way is to save it on DB and check before call if it has expired already but considering it's just 1 access_token it might be overkill. Another I am considering is session but how reliable are sessions for keeping access tokens?

Comment: How about save it to cache (like Redis)?

Comment: feels overkill to setup redis to save a token as well don't you think? I think currently Im leaning towards sessions

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic solution that you can extend.

```
class ThirdPartyAPI
  def things
    retried = false
    access_token = fetch_access_token

    begin
      # Request things from the API using access_token
    rescue AccessTokenExpiredError
      raise if retried

      access_token = fetch_access_token(force: true)
      retried = true
      retry
    end
  end

  private

  def fetch_access_token(force: false)
    Rails.cache.fetch('cool_api/access_token', expires_in: 1.hour, force: force) do
      # Call the API to get a new access token and return it
    end
  end
end
```

You could use `ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore` as a cache store implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could save it in a high performance cache store (Memcache, Redis etc.) probably already in use by your application. Set the expiration time to be same as that of your token expiration time.

An overview of the flow will look like this:

> - Look up for access token in the cache store.
> - If it's a hit, use the token.
> - Else If it's a miss, request a new token, write to cache store and use it.

You could add conditions to handle expired tokens found in cache hit and request new tokens.

Also, I'm not sure about your use case but if the 3rd party access token is a Global one then it makes sense to use this approach rather then going for a session based, which would be specific to user session.